# Handling errors in contact form - Get the right finction

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, methods, material-ui

I have created a form using material-ui with React.
I have got some issues with my submit method.
I am displaying a snackbar to inform user of the success of submission, and also a snackbar to alert the user that required fields are missing.
My issue is in case user didn't fill all fields, but after a second attempt finally makes it with success. My alert snackbar is still appearing but I want to show the success snackbar. Not sure what I need to change in my method.

```
 submit = () => {
    const {
      firstName,
      lastName,
      email,
      phone,
      date,
      time,
      projectStages,
      projectDescription,
      budgets,
      mainObjectives,
      applicationTypes,
    } = this.state
    // eslint-disable-next-line max-len
    if (lastName && firstName && email && phone) {
      this.setState({
        lastName,
        firstName,
        email,
        phone,
        date,
        time,
        projectStages,
        projectDescription,
        budgets,
        mainObjectives,
        applicationTypes,
      })
      document.getElementById('snackbar').style.display = 'block'
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({ open: false })
      }, 2000)
      // eslint-disable-next-line max-len
      this.saveMessage(firstName, lastName, phone, email, date, time, projectStages, projectDescription, budgets, mainObjectives, applicationTypes)
    } else {
      document.getElementById('snackbar').style.display = 'block'
      document.getElementById('snackbar').style.backgroundColor = 'red'
      document.getElementById('snackbar').textContent = 'Please fill in all required fields'
      setTimeout(() => {
        document.getElementById('snackbar').style.display = 'none'
      }, 2000)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Clear your timer before set it again

```
timer && clearTimeout(timer);
```